# How to encapsulate the assignment after load file Angular?

Tags: angular

There are two services.
One of them has a method that uploads a file:

```
public async loadLayersConfig(): Promise<Config> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/layers.config.json");
}
```

How to encapsulate the assignment `config` after getting the file?
I do it like this:

```
const config = await loadLayersConfig();
this.service.setConfig(config); // Here
```

T-e, I don’t like what happens in another area of ​​responsibility:

```
this.service.setConfig(config);
```

Wrap in another promise? And set config in between?

Comment: Promise<Config>=> Observable<Config>

Comment: loadLayersConfig().subscribe(config=>
this.service.setConfig(config));

Comment: Yes, I did the same, so I dislike that this.service.setConfig(config) is not encaplusated in service and is controlled from usage side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check angular.io to understand how to use httpClient (https://angular.io/guide/http)

```
public async loadLayersConfig(): Observable<Config> {
     return this.http.get("./assets/layers.config.json");
}



loadLayersConfig().subscribe(config=> this.service.setConfig(config));
```

---

Edit

```
 public async loadLayersConfig(): Observable<Config> {
         return this.http.get("./assets/layers.config.json").pipe(tap(config=> this.setConfig(config));
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same, so I dislike that `this.service.setConfig(config)` is not encaplusated in service and is controlled from usage side

Comment: ah in this case you need to use tap in your  service